# Issue with div scroll left and right javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, schedule

I tried everything but with no luck. I dont know what i did wrong. Please help me!
All I wanted to do is to create a button that can scroll right and left of the schedule-background-container.

Thank you in advance for any help

html

```
<div id="schedule-background">
<div id="schedule-heading-container">
    <div id="schedule-button-right"></div>
    <div id="schedule-button-left"></div>
    <div id="schedule-background-overall">
        <div class="schedule-background-container">
                <h2 class="schedule-date">July 23</h2>

            <ul class="schedule-ul">
                <li class="schedule-title"><a href="#">Homework</a>
                </li>
                <li class="schedule-other">10:00AM</li>
                <li class="schedule-title"><a href="#">Firework</a>
                </li>
                <li class="schedule-other">11:00AM</li>
                <li class="schedule-title"><a href="#">Dexter</a>
                </li>
                <li class="schedule-other">12:00PM</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="schedule-background-container">
                <h2 class="schedule-date">July 24</h2>

            <ul class="schedule-ul">
                <li class="schedule-title"><a href="#"> hello</a>
                </li>
                <li class="schedule-other">9:30am</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#schedule-button-right {
background-color: grey;
position: absolute;
width: 9px;
height: 8px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 145px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 2;
}
#schedule-button-left {
background-color: grey;
position: absolute;
width: 9px;
height: 8px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 2;
}
#schedule-background {
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 120px;
margin-left: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
width:160px;
height: 600px;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}
#schedule-heading-container {
background: #088a26;
width: 160px;
height: 25px;
}
#schedule-background-overall {
min-width: 320px;
float: left;
position:relative;
}
.schedule-background-container {
width:160px;
height:600px;
float: left;
position:relative;
}
.schedule-date {
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 0;
padding-top: 3px;
font: Calibri;
font-size: 18px;
}
.schedule-title {
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
}
.schedule-other {
font-size: 12px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.schedule-ul {
position:relative;
margin-top:10px;
height:550px;
list-style:none;
padding-left: 10px;
}
.schedule-ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color:#0d5887;
}
.schedule-ul li a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $item = $('div#schedule-background-overall');
$('div#schedule-button-right').click(function () {
    $item.animate({
        'left': '-=160px'
    }, 'slow');
});
$('div#schedule-button-left').click(function () {
    $item.animate({
        'left': '+=160px'
    }, 'slow');
});
});
```

To make it easier here is the code in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/stanley1943/W7PMS/)

Again, Thank you!!!
--------------------------Solved---------------------
Didnt load library! Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer for the benefit of future readers and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two errors from what I can see. One is the $ symbol missing in the below line:

`var $item = ('div#schedule-background-overall');`

Change it to: `var $item = $('div#schedule-background-overall');`

Other is the capital "L" in the below:

```
$('div#schedule-button-right').click(function () {
  $item.animate({
    'Left': '-=160px' // Change it to left in all lower-case
  }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: I have changed everything you mentioned but still no luck.

Comment: strange, what is the error now? check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/TztBa/) with my changes for a working version.

Comment: may be jq libraries not included

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding `$` as 
`var $item = $('div#schedule-background-overall');`

Answer (score 1):

Try assiging margins

```
 $item.animate({'margin-Left': '160px'},slow);
```

and it should be

```
 var $item = $('div#schedule-background-overall');
```